# Can WINE open standalone Windows Application under Linux?

Tags: java, linux, windows, wine

I just wonder if WINE can open Windows Application under Linux? I have a Windows standalone application which reads some files, runs its own algorithm, and writes results into some files.

If the answer is yes, do you have to have WINE open under Linux and open Windows standalone through WINE like [codeweavers](http://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/mac/mactutorial/run_only)?

My ultimate question is this: I have an algorithm coded in Java, at the moment my algorithm repeatedly calls the Windows standalone. **If I run my java program under Linux, is it possible to call a Windows application and run it normally with the help of WINE?**

I'm not a computer science graduate and I have limited IT knowledge. I appreciate any help and suggestion. Cheers!

Comment: That's the whole purpose of WINE isn't it? To run Windows stuff under Linux?

Comment: You don't need to be a "computer science graduate" to try it out. Just fire up a Linux distro with Wine installed.

Comment: thanks @assylias for making my question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, wine can make windows programs to run on linux. But if you are calling a stand alone windows program, I think it is not possible. Because, the paths , i mean directories are different and all the programs come in the package are different with windows and linux. Isn't it?

Comment: WINE is for calling Windows programs. You can install them, run them, access its own file system.